# SQL Select unique values by one column with the latest value by another column

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table structure:

```
leads:

name  | email | date
-------------------------------------------------------
John  | john@mail.com  | 2020-01-21
J     | john@mail.com  | 2020-01-20
Alex  | alex@mail.com  | 2020-01-19
A     | alex@mail.com  | 2020-01-18
James | james@mail.com | 2020-01-17
```

I need to select only rows with UNIQUE emails and the LATEST associated name so the expected result is:

```
name  | email | date
-------------------------------------------------------
John  | john@mail.com  | 2020-01-21
Alex  | alex@mail.com  | 2020-01-19
James | james@mail.com | 2020-01-17
```

Comment: What did you try, and what went wrong with it?

Comment: i build the query with laravel php framework and tried a lot of different ways but mostly all of them throws the following error `GROUP BY contains nonaggregated column 'leads.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause`

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use not exists

```
select * from tbl a 
where not exist(select 1 from tbl b where a.email = b.email  and a.date < b.date)
```

Comment: For a big table is good idea to create a composite index on email and date columns.